# Is the map $T_X |_S (p) := \exp{X(p)}$ a diffeomorphism onto its image?

Tags: differential-geometry, riemannian-geometry, geodesic

### Preliminaries

The exponential map $\exp : TM \rightarrow M$ is defined by $\exp{(v)} = \gamma_v (1) $ where $\gamma_v$ denotes the geodesic starting at $p \in M$ and initial velocity $v \in T_p M$. The restricted exponential map $\left. \exp \right|_{T_p M}$ is denoted $\exp_p$.

### Setup

Let $(M, g)$ be a smooth, compact Riemannian n-manifold without boundary. Let $S \subset M$ denote a smooth submanifold of codimension-0 with boundary. Fix $X \in \mathfrak{X}(M)$.

### Question

Let $T_X : M \rightarrow M$ be defined by
$$
T_X (p) := \exp{(X(p))}
$$

Are there any conditions on $X$ such that the restriction $\left. T_X \right|_{S} $ becomes a diffeomorphism onto its image?

### Notes

I am aware that the exponential mapping restricted to $T_p M$ is a diffeomorphism on some neighborhood of the origin. I would guess that we would need to specify that $X$ belong to the intersection of all the neighborhoods where where $\exp$ is a diffeomorphism for each $p \in M$. But I am not sure.

### Differential in terms of Jacobi fields

So to answer @Artic Char in the comments I will do the computation by applying the chain rule. Disclaimer: I'm not sure if the computations below are correct.

The differential of the exponential map at $(p, v) \in T M$ can be expressed in terms of Jacobi fields. We can write
$$
\begin{aligned}
d_{(p, v)} (\exp) : T_{(p, v)}(T M) &\rightarrow T_{\exp_p(v)} M\\
(\hat{p}, \hat{v}) &\mapsto J(1)
\end{aligned}
$$
where $J$ is the Jacobi field along the geodesic $\gamma(t) = \exp_p(tv)$, satisfying initial conditions $J(0) = \hat{p}$ and $D_t J(0) = \hat{v}$.

From another side, we can work in natural coordinates around $p$ so that we make the identification $T_{(p, v)}(T M)$ with $\mathbb{R}^n \times \mathbb{R}^n$ and similarly with $T_pM$ and $\mathbb{R}^n$. The differential of a vector field is then given by $ d_p X(v) = (v, \Lambda v)$ where $\Lambda$ is a linear operator $\mathbb{R}^n \rightarrow \mathbb{R}^n$. Hence by the chain rule we have that

$$
\begin{aligned}
d_p T_X(v) = J(1)
\end{aligned}
$$
where J is the solution to the Jacobi equation (in the given coordinates) along the geodesic $\gamma_{X(p)}$ with initial conditions $J(0) = v$, $D_t J(0) = \Lambda v$.

Comment: What do you mean when you say to fix $X\in TM$? Do you mean a section? And what does $\exp X(pj$ mean? Presumably $\exp_p X(p)$?

Comment: Sorry I meant a smooth vector field. You are also correct on the second point.

Comment: Do you know the Cartan-Hadamard Theorem? The exponential (at a fixed point) is a diffeomorphism from the tangent space at that point onto the manifold when the manifold is simply connected and of non-positive curvature.

Comment: Not yet, unfortunately. I was reading about the exponential map in Lee’s book (riemannian one) and thought of this question.

Comment: Looks like the differential of your map can be written down as some Jacobi field. Have you learn that yet?

Comment: Hi @ArcticChar, I have added some information to the question. I am unsure of the validity of the computations above. Maybe you can take a look? Many thanks in advance.

Comment: @TedShifrin Thank you for your suggestion. However, I would like to remain as general as possible on the restrictions on $M$. So I will change the question so that the only thing we know is that $M$ be compact.

Comment: I was not pretending to answer your question. I was adding that to your knowledge base, along with what you already said in "Notes."

Comment: For instance, zero vector field would do the job. Similarly, if $S$ is compact, then each vector field sufficiently close to zero.

Answer (score 1):

A simple sufficient condition is that $X=0$. Then the map $T_X$ you defined is the identity map, hence, its restriction to any submanifold is a diffeomorphism to the image.